# Write a method that will convert the supplied binary digit (as a string) to a decimal number

Tags: java, binary

The aim of this method is to convert the supplied binary digit (as a string) to a decimal number, but I am not getting the result the question wants with the code I have for example `convertToDecimal("01101011") = 107`, and I'm am unsure I believe im converting the binary to decimal number right. 
for example:

Test

```
System.out.println(convertToDecimal("11001101")); = 205
```

ive tried a while loop and creating ints but it's just not giving me the same results

```
public static int binaryToDecimal(String binary) {
     int decimal = 0;
     int power = 0;
     int currentIndex = binary.length() - 1;
     while (currentIndex>=0) {
         int currentDigit = binary.charAt(currentIndex) - '0';  
         decimal += currentDigit * Math.pow(2, power);
         power++;
         currentIndex--;
     }
     return decimal;
 }
```

I expected to the output to be:

```
convertToDecimal("01101011") = 107 
convertToDecimal("00001011") = 11    ,  
System.out.println(convertToDecimal("11001101")); = 205
```

but none were right

Comment: What did you actually get? We need to see that as well, if we are to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add results that you get?

Comment: You should get exactly what you expected:
107, 11, 205

Comment: Your function is called `binaryToDecimal` but you are calling `convertToDecimal`. Is that a copy-paste error or are you calling the wrong method?

Comment: Ok, it's actually working now, I have no idea why it is wasnt working before, the code is right and thanks to you all for helping. im new to this website so should I delete this post or just keep it up since its correct?

Comment: Since your issue isn't reproducible, yes you should delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, and it worked. But I need to make one simple change:

```
System.out.println(convertToDecimal("11001101")); = 205
```

must be changed to:

```
System.out.println(binaryToDecimal("11001101")); = 205
```

because **binaryToDecimal()** is the actual name of your function:

```
public static int binaryToDecimal(String binary) {
     int decimal = 0;
     int power = 0;
     int currentIndex = binary.length() - 1;
     while (currentIndex>=0) {
         int currentDigit = binary.charAt(currentIndex) - '0';  
         decimal += currentDigit * Math.pow(2, power);
         power++;
         currentIndex--;
     }
     return decimal;
 }
```

After that, it all works fine.